# Divisibility of a polynomial defined on a vector space (Lie algebra)

Tags: vector-spaces, lie-algebras

I want to prove the following:

> If $f: \mathfrak{h} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a polynomial function such that $f \left( H \right) = 0$ whenever $\langle \alpha, H \rangle = 0$, then $f$ is divisible in the space of polynomials by $\langle \alpha, H \rangle$.

Here, $\mathfrak{h}$ is a finite dimensional complex Lie algebra, and $0 \neq \alpha \in \mathfrak{h}$. Also, a definition of polynomial on a finite dimensional Lie algebra is given as

> **Definition:** A function $P: \mathfrak{h} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a polynomial if it is a polynomial in the coordinates with respect to any given basis.

To prove the claim, I have done the following:

We start with an orthonormal basis for $\mathfrak{h}$, given by $\left\lbrace \dfrac{\alpha}{\| \alpha \|}, H_1, H_2, \cdots, H_{r-1} \right\rbrace$ (assume that $\dim \mathfrak{h} = r$).

Then, if $H = z_1 \alpha + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{r - 1} z_{i + 1} H_i$, we have $\langle \alpha, H \rangle = z_1$ (a polynomial). Also, in these coordinates, we can write

$$f \left( H \right) = \sum\limits_{n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_r \geq 0} c_{n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_r} z_1^{n_1}z_2^{n_2}\cdots z_r^{n_r},$$

where $c_{n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_r} \in \mathbb{C}$, and there are only finitely many non-zero coefficients.

With this, we only have to prove that $n_1 > 0$ for all the terms. I have no idea how to proceed for this. I tried using a contradiction. I assumed that there is some term with $n_1 = 0$. But, then I could not conclude that all other coordinates must also be zero. Is there some way to do it? Is it possible we can assume that the coordinates are all non-negative for some $H \in \mathfrak{H}$?

Comment: I'd think the Nullstellensatz tells you right away that $\langle \alpha, H \rangle$ divides some power of $f$, but since $\langle \alpha, H \rangle$ is linear (hence irreducible) then it must already divide $f$ itself.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: I was thinking more on the terms of taking some $H \in \mathfrak{h}$ such that all the coordinates except $z_1$ are positive and $z_1 = 0$. Then, since we have started with an orthonormal basis, this would tell us that $H$ is orthogonal to $\alpha$ and hence $f \left( H \right) = 0$. If $f$ had any term with non-zero power of $z_1$, then the value would be positive (since all the coordinates are positive). The only doubt I have in this is whether we can choose such an element? At least in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ it looks like we can.